# Is the main point of romanticism the subjective and emotional experience of things?

Tags: romanticism

I feel the idea of romanticism which distinguishes it from other movements, in particular the Enlightenment, is really the emphasis on *the subjective and emotional **experience*** of things, in opposition to the *objective and analytical **observation*** of things.

Is that correct?

### Examples

One example is John Keats. One [letter to Charles Dilke](https://news.lettersofnote.com/p/dirty-bacon-dirtier-eggs-and-dirtiest) (1819) illustrates the point:

> Talking of Pleasure, this moment I was writing with one hand, and with the other holding to my Mouth a Nectarine—good God how fine. It went down soft, pulpy, slushy, oozy—all its delicious embonpoint melted down my throat like a large beatified Strawberry. I shall certainly breed. Now I come to my request. Should you like me for a neighbour again? Come, plump it out, I won’t blush.

A precursor of this tradition is Rousseau with *Julie; or, The New Heloise* (1761), and followers are Baudelaire ("L'Albatros", 1861) and Rimbaud ("Sensation", 1870).

These pieces bring the reader into ***experiencing in a sensitive way*** the idea/world/feeling the author wants to transmit/recreate via their piece.

In comparison, some fictitious novels such as *Supplément au voyage de Bougainville* (philosophical tale), or *Madame Bovary* (realistic novel) bring the author ***to think and then to observe*** (in the latter), or ***to observe and then to think*** (in the former).

I suppose drawing a similar parallel in music would be more difficult but possible.

Comment: As impressions go, your summary is fine with one useful caveat: it's possible to orthogonalize and reify the differences between these partitions, erasing the considerable overlap(s). At their core -- 1) these cohort mindsets consider time differently: the Romantics were rebelling against the clockwork universe of the Enlightenment. 2) they had differing perspectives on the possibilities of human knowledge: the Romantics were moving away from the deterministic, omniscient *Voltairean eye* in acknowledging human fallibility and imperfection

Comment: Yes, Descartes' foundationalism was being challenged.

Comment: The possibility of human perfection is, imo, a core principle of Christian Western Civ, implicit in biblical injunctions to control and/or master nature. Enlightenment thought was a continuation of this insofar as it advanced anti-scholastic frameworks criticizing static, received knowledge and promoted critical human capacities for experimentation and observation -- the invention of science, if you will.

Comment: That is my suggestion, yes, and apparently your interpretation. FWIW.

Comment: @DJohnson I edited my question accordingly, so I erased my comments. Could you give examples of romantics acknowledging human fallibility and imperfection?

Comment: I would argue that this evolution, if that's what it is, is implicit in the move away from deterministic certitude expressed in unquestioning Christian (Catholic) belief and faith with an increasing embrace of secular, modern doubt and uncertainty. But specific references? I'll have to think about it.

Comment: You're running out of questions about my comments. It's the opposite, Enlightenment thinkers were challenging Christian (Catholic) unquestioning beliefs in faith.

Comment: Not things, *people*. Last time I look things don't experience anything.

Comment: @Lambie people experience or observe things

Comment: Check out Brown's *Thing Theory* for a full discussion of the meaning of *things*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_theory

Comment: @DJohnson your comments would make an excellent answer